# How to hide or gray out an item in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

As the title says :) I thought that I could access elements same as in a linked list, but I only found `Items.GetItemAt(index)`. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to Hide/Gray out in an event ?

Comment: What exactly are you searching for? A specific number...a name of an element. What makes it an item you don't want anymore?

Comment: are you using winforms or wpf? Just checking as your tag says wpf, if that is the case are you databinding?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide on an event, when I click some specific button. Each element is a grid that contains an image and two buttons. I would like to hide an image or to gray it out by changing its opacity.

Comment: @ Sapy I'm using WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items in the `ListView` are ViewModels, you can bind to a property (e.g. IsDisabled) and use that to trigger a style change to set a different opacity value.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDisabled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```